# How to set environment variables for external app

Tags: .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, environment-variables

I am developing a .NET 4.0 class, which calls an external app that reads one parameter from the environment.

However, the Environment class can be modified from any thread. And there's another obvious problem when using two instances of my class which need different value in the variable.

What is the correct way to set independent environment variables when calling an external application?

**NOTE:** I have updated the question, heavily changing the wording, because I was asking the wrong question. If some comment seems out of place, maybe you should check the edit history.

Comment: This might be a bad design. Environment variables are meant to be used at operating environment scope. You should consider using local variables (thread level). What exactly is your scenario for using the environment variables in your program?

Comment: That's just not the right way to do this.  Use the ProcessStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables property instead so you'll modify the environment for the process you start instead of your own.

Comment: @GabiTurliu - I think it's pretty clear. I have to call another application which reads an environment variable. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @HansPassant - Thank you! That's exactly what I needed. I think I'll reword the question so you can put this as an answer.

Comment: @HansPassant - Now I think I'm asking the right question :-)